# Sequential Task Execution Issue in Ansible Playbook after Adding Loop Functionality

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I'm trying to make a playbook by integrating variables for the user name. Everything is working well and I'm getting the desired result, but the problem is that it stops at the end of the 1st task (Copy the Firefox profile folder) and the 2nd task isn't executed, and I don't understand why.
It's only since I added the loop function.
Before, with absolute paths, the two tasks followed each other well.
Does anyone know why?

```
- name: Copy the Firefox profile folder
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "/home/me/ansible/ansible_clients/role-firefox/templates/profiles/mozilla/.mozilla/firefox/xxgeosl7.test"
    dest: "/home/{{ item.id }}/.mozilla/firefox/xxgeosl7.test"
    owner: "{{ item.id }}"
    group: "{{ item.id }}"
    mode: 0755
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  register: copy_folder
  tags: add-profil


- name: Read the contents of the profiles.ini file
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: cat "/home/{{ item.id }}/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini"
  loop: "{{ users }}"
  register: content_profiles_ini
  tags: add-profil
```

variable file:

```
users:
  - id: paul
  - id: jack
```

EDIT:
Here are the logs:

```
TASK [role-firefox : Copy the Firefox profile folder] ************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [192.168.100.49] (item=paul) => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "checksum": "d3b188859881814a9e9647e180adee84d3ab57ba", "gid": 0, "group": "root", "item": {"id": "paul"}, "mode": "0755", "msg": "chown failed: failed to look up user paul", "owner": "root", "path": "/home/paul", "size": 4096, "state": "directory", "uid": 0}
ok: [192.168.100.49] => (item=jack)
PLAY RECAP
```

Comment: have you tried with -vvv to see the verbose output? Can you share it ?

Comment: I've understood why he doesn't continue.

In my case, it's normal that it doesn't find the 1st user, but the 2nd does exist. How can I get it to ignore the error and continue with the rest of the tasks with the users that have been matched?

Comment: see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755884/ansible-ignoring-errors-in-a-loop